# asp.net 2.0: best data structure to bind to gridview

Tags: gridview, dataset, asp.net-2.0

For the most part, the application I'm working on deals with object, and I can bind a list of objects to a gridview without any problems.

However, in a couple of cases, I want to display the results of a multi-table join in a gridview.  The current code uses a dataset, which is pretty easy, but I'm wondering if there's a better/more efficient way to do this.

We don't need most of the features of the dataset - data is read-only, and there will not be a large number of records in most cases.  (i.e. probably no more than 200, and usually 10-20)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the DataReader whenever possible. There are times when a DataSet is more appropriate, such as the two situations listed below. These came from the article, "[Why I Don't Use DataSets in My ASP.NET Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513222547/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx)". Also check out the follow up article, "[More On Why I Don't Use DataSets in My ASP.NET Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125131938/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051805-1.aspx)".

> 1. In a desktop, WinForms application. Consider a desktop-based
>      data entry-type program. A user might
>      fire up the program, load up the sales
>      data from some database server, make
>      some changes, and then want to save
>      those changes. This is an ideal
>      situation for the DataSet. It allows
>      the data to be read into a DataSet
>      residing in the client's memory, which
>      affords the user the ability to work
>      on the data without needing to
>      constantly make trips back to the
>      database. Upon completing editing the
>      data, they can do a batch update,
>      gracefully handling any changes that
>      may have occurred while the user was
>      working with the data in a
>      disconnected state. Furthermore, since
>      the DataSet is a disconnected data
>      store, this data can be taken offline.
>      A salesman traveling to a client's
>      site could load this data and be able
>      to review the data on his laptop while
>      in transit, or while at the client's
>      office.
> 2. For sending/receiving remote database information or for allowing
>      communication between disparate
>      platforms.  Since a DataSet can be
>      serialized/deserialized into XML so
>      easily, they are a prime candidate for
>      sending information across physical
>      boundaries or as a means of
>      serializing data into a
>      platform-neutral format. For example,
>      if you want to return database data
>      from a Web service, one option is to
>      simply read the database data into a
>      DataSet and then return the DataSet
>      from the Web service method. The
>      DataSet will automatically be
>      serialized into XML and sent over the
>      wire. (Personally I don't recommend
>      returning data from a Web service in
>      this manner. Rather, I prefer to use
>      custom business objects - it allows a
>      finer degree of control over the XML
>      serialization, provides a much lighter
>      return payload, and appears less
>      architecture-specific.